# Array ValueCount

Tags: c, arrays, char

Suppose I have an array 
`char buf[5];` 
that has a value stored in it, say `"365"`. 
How can I count the number of digits present in that value?  In this example, the answer is 3 (3, 6, 5)?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do it for you:

```
int length = strlen(buf);
int digits = 0;

for(int i=0; i< length; ++i) {
    if(isdigit(buf[i]))
        ++digits;   
}

printf( "Your word has %d digits in it\n", digits );
```

Comment: isdigit is C++ can i implement it in C?

Comment: @kiran: `isdigit()` was in C before there was a C++.  It is declared in `<ctype.h>` (character type classification functions) and is part of the standard C library.

Answer (score 0):

The `isdigit()` function can be used only when variable has integer value. The function `isdigit()` returns non-zero if its argument is a digit between `'0'` and `'9'`. Otherwise, zero is returned. You can understand it with help of following example.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    c = buf[5];
    if ( isdigit(c) )
        printf( "You entered the digit %c\n", c );
}
```

Comment: I've fixed a number of presentation problems for you.  To enter code, type it (or copy it) with no tabs, and then use the code button `{}` above the edit box to indent it all by the four spaces which converts it into 'code'.  You now just have a problem that `buf` is undefined, and your code has no loop in it where a loop is needed.

Comment: NP: assuming that you include `char buf[5] = "365";` as stipulated in the question, your code is trying to access a non-existent element of `buf`, still.  I recommend editing your answer into a compiling, working program that produces 3 as output as requested.